# Define symmetric function for a subset of variables

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I apologize if this question has been asked already. I did some research and found some solutions but none of them was general enough for what I need.

So, I defined the following function:

```
g[i_][a_, b_, c_] := Subsuperscript[g, {a, b, c}, {i}]
```

and now I would like to specify that if the variable `i` is equal to 8 then the function is Orderless (symmetric) with respect to the variables `a` and `b`.

Is there any way of doing that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like `g[8][b_, a_, c_] /; ! OrderedQ[{b, a}] := Subsuperscript[g, {a, b, c}, {8}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[g]

g[8][OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, b_], c_] :=  Subsuperscript[g, {a, b, c}, {8}]

g[i_][a_, b_, c_] := Subsuperscript[g, {a, b, c}, {i}]
```

***Examples:***

```
{g[2][y, x, z], g[8][y, x, z], g[8][5, 1, u], g[8][3, 2, 1]}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you very much!