# Assume symmetric F[a,b] = F[b,a] when CountDistinct and similar functions

Tags: list-manipulation, function-comparison

I wonder how I can tell Mathematica to regard the following expressions: `F[a,b]` and `F[b,a]` as being equal, so for example `CountDistinct[{F[a,b], F[b,a]}]` would yield 1 and
`CountDistinct[{F[a,b] F[x1,x2], F[b,a] F[x1,x2], F[a,b] F[x2,x1], F[x1,x2] F[a,b]}]` would also yield 1. Similarly, `DeleteDuplicates[{F[a,b], F[b,a]}]` would return either F[a,b] or F[b,a]. I would like this property to be somehow able to be defined globally, so every function recognizes F as being symmetric in its arguments. I assume that if somehow Mathematica returned `True` to `F[a,b] == F[b,a]`, then it would work automatically. I searched but did not find anything that would address this... one thing that seems to work is to set `F[a_,b_]:= f[a b]`, or some other symmetric expression and it seems to be working, but I'm worried that this adds unnecessary complexity to the verification, moreover, I tried `F[a_,b_]:=f[Abs[a-b]]` (which is closer to the real purpose), but this time I don't get `True` out of `F[a,b] == F[b,a]` (why?).

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220384/define-symmetric-function-for-a-subset-of-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the attribute `Orderless` to a function `F` with two arguments could be one option. This attribute orders the the arguments of `F` on input:

[image: Orderless]

The problem/caveat of this approach is that `Orderless` functions appear only with their arguments canonically ordered (e.g.: `F[b,a]` returns `F[a,b]`) which can only be prevented by using `Hold`: `Hold[F[b, a]]` returns `Hold[F[b, a]]`. If `F[a,b]=F[b,a]` in all contexts then this should not be a problem.

If `F[a,b]=F[b,a]` holds only in certain contexts one could use a rule like

```
F[a_, b_] /; Sort[{a, b}] =!= {a, b} :> F[b, a]
```

in those contexts to canonically order the expressions containing `F` e.g.

[image: Rule]
.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great solution!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely they will try out your solution.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful